# How to use MySql query queue in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a site where it will sell some digital products, I am using PHP (PDO) with MySql. The site ran good so far, but as the user base develops I am facing some issues.

If the stock of the product is only 1, and 2 users placed an order at the same time, the database is going into -1 and the order is getting confirmed for both of the users. How can I queue the query so that the users come one by one?

```
$res = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE true', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: You need to learn about transactions.

Comment: As said by @Barmar you need SQL transactions. This is a mechanism that makes sure the data you read is not modified it by someone else why you are working on it. It locks the data you seek (here the stock level).

Answer (score 0):

Fetch orders from Database,before processing your logic,put first record status as processing and  then after all your logic update record status as normal state.Main thing here is that,fetch data from database with following query.

"select * from data_table where status='available' ".

It's may be helpful.